# How to make login box into a reusable UI component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, uicomponents

Using jQuery, how would I go about making a reusable UI component from this login box, so that it could be used twice on one page?

**jQuery:**

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.loginBox = function () {

    this.html('<div class="loginContainer"><div class="formContainer"><form action="api.yoursite.com/login" class="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post"><fieldset class="loginFields"><legend>User Login</legend><h1>User Login</h1><input autofocus class="loginID" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Apple ID" required /><input class="loginPassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><button class="loginSubmit" name="submit" type="submit">Login to your account</button></fieldset></form></div></div>');

    $(".loginForm").submit(function () {

      var username = $(this).find(".loginID").val();
      var password = $(this).find(".loginPassword").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api.yoursite.com/login",
        data: { username: username, password: password },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("succeeded");
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log("failed");
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

    return this; // make this plug-in chainable
  };

}(jQuery));

var loginOne = $("#loginOne").loginBox();
var loginTwo = $("#loginTwo").loginBox();
```

Am I best suited taking cues from a framework like [Ink.js](http://ink.sapo.pt/js/ui) and loading separate scripts for each component, or is there a simpler approach?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="loginOne"></div>

    <br />

    <div id="loginTwo"></div>

</body>
```

**Update**: I've tied two separate form instances to a single script - will it manage separate state and common behavior for each of them, or is this approach problematic?

Comment: If you want to use this code only on this page , you can take the html code inside container <div> and paste it in another div . Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: No, the code should be reusable, so that it can be used multiple times across a site, and twice on one page if need be. I could see an additional <div> being helpful if dynamically appending each instance of this login box to a container and giving it an ID, but I don't think that's what you're asking. Each form instance will need to be a separate object.

Comment: Why would you want to have two login boxes on one page?

Comment: Plenty of sites have this. My sample HTML has the login boxes next to each other for simplicity's sake. But a more realistic example would be an instance in the header or footer, and another in the content body. Also, they're not necessarily using the exact same CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your code would work, however, I have some suggestions:

- I would have added a hidden login template to the DOM that you can `clone()` and re-use. Keeping the HTML inline in the javascript will start becoming troublesome when you want some more complex functionality and/or layout.
- You can't simply do `var username = $(".loginID").val();`. This will always get you the first element with class `loginID`. You need to make use of the `this` pointer when dealing with multiple instances.
- Pass the `data` as an object literal. Change `data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password` to `data: { username: username, password: password }`.

Just my two cents.

```
var Loginbox = (function($){

    function loginbox(){

        this.$element = $('.logintemplate').clone()
                                           .removeClass('logintemplate');
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    loginbox.prototype = {
        bindEvents: function(){

            var that = this;

            this.$element.find('.send').on('click', function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/echo/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        username: that.$element.find('.username').val(), 
                        password: that.$element.find('.password').val() 
                    }

                }).done(function(data){
                     console.log('done');
                }).fail(function(){
                    console.log('fail');
                });

            });
        }
    };

    return loginbox;

})(jQuery);

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var box = new Loginbox();
    $('body').append(box.$element.show());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJK4p/

Comment: I've modified my two variables inside the Ajax call, utilizing .find() - ie, var username = $(this).find(".loginID").val(); Not sure if this is what you had in mind. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @user2761994 No problem. I would have done something like this. Just let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Here are some questions: 1) Why's the value of url 'echo/json'? I need it to be 'api.yoursite.com/login' but will this be an issue? 2) I'm accustomed to seeing success and error in the ajax call - assuming .done and .fail are also acceptable? 3) Wouldn't it be better to assign each login box its own ID (there will never be more than 2 on a page)? That way they could more easily be styled differently if so desired 4) I've created another fiddle with some updated code. I added back in the form elements, since a requirement is that I utilize HTML5 semantics: http://jsfiddle.net/manh2244/ttuP4/1/

Comment: @user2761994 1. It's just a test url that works with jsfiddle for dummy ajax calls. 2. They are equivalent 3. Sure, that's up to you 4. Looks good!